# Grouping Nested Objects with Dynamic Keys (Using Lodash)

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects, lodash

I'm querying Firebase to get some data to throw into Chart.js. Here's how I've laid out my data:

```
{
  "20160428": {
    "follow": 13,
    "host": 6,
    "raid": 1,
    "substreak": 1,
    "tip": 1
  },
  "20160429": {
    "follow": 15,
    "host": 21,
    "raid": 2,
    "substreak": 4
  },
  "20160430": {
    "follow": 4
  },
  "20160501": {
    "follow": 11,
    "host": 15,
    "subscription": 4,
    "substreak": 5
  },
  "20160502": {
    "follow": 2,
    "host": 6,
    "subscription": 1,
    "substreak": 4
  },
  "20160503": {
    "follow": 2
  }
}
```

As you can see, each object is keyed off by a timestamp and events don't always appear in every object (but there are a finite number of events). Here's how I'd like the data to look so I can feed it into Chart.js:

```
labels: ["20160428", "20160429", "20160430", ...]

{
  "follow": [13, 15, 4, 11, 2, 2],
  "host": [6, 21, 0, 15, 6, 0],
  "raid": [1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  "subscription": [0, 0, 0, 4, 1, 0]
  "substreak": [1, 4, 0, 5, 4, 0]
  "tip": [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

I've played with Lodash's `groupBy` and similar functions, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track. I wouldn't mind doing this `x` times either per event, but at this point I can't change the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a defined set of keys that you want to group then you have to:

1. Use [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) to pluck values with [compact()](https://lodash.com/docs#compact) to get non-null values from the object collection from the defined set of keys.
2. Build the result using [zipObject()](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObject) from the defined keys and values obtained from the first step.

---

```
var keys = ["follow", "host", "raid", "substreak", "tip", "subscription"];
var values = _.map(keys, key => _(data).map(key).compact().value());
var result = _.zipObject(keys, values);
```

```js
var data = {
  "20160428": { "follow": 13, "host": 6, "raid": 1, "substreak": 1, "tip": 1 },
  "20160429": { "follow": 15, "host": 21, "raid": 2, "substreak": 4 },
  "20160430": { "follow": 4 },
  "20160501": { "follow": 11, "host": 15, "subscription": 4, "substreak": 5 },
  "20160502": { "follow": 2, "host": 6, "subscription": 1, "substreak": 4 },
  "20160503": { "follow": 2 }
};

var keys = ["follow", "host", "raid", "substreak", "tip", "subscription"];
var values = _.map(keys, key => _(data).map(key).compact().value());
var result = _.zipObject(keys, values);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

If you want to group them from all the keys present in the object collection then you can:

1. Get all the unique keys by:

   - [map()](https://lodash.com/docs#map) each data object inside the object collection
   - [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) the resulting array
   - Use [uniq()](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq) to get all unique keys from the flattened array.
2. Use the methodology in the first example to get the values and build the object.

---

```
var keys = _(data).map(_.keys).flatten().uniq().value();
var values = _.map(keys, key => _(data).map(key).compact().value());
var result = _.zipObject(keys, values);
```

```js
var data = {
  "20160428": { "follow": 13, "host": 6, "raid": 1, "substreak": 1, "tip": 1 },
  "20160429": { "follow": 15, "host": 21, "raid": 2, "substreak": 4 },
  "20160430": { "follow": 4 },
  "20160501": { "follow": 11, "host": 15, "subscription": 4, "substreak": 5 },
  "20160502": { "follow": 2, "host": 6, "subscription": 1, "substreak": 4 },
  "20160503": { "follow": 2 }
};

var keys = _(data).map(_.keys).flatten().uniq().value();
var values = _.map(keys, key => _(data).map(key).compact().value());
var result = _.zipObject(keys, values);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.11.2/lodash.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use plain javascript and some loops.

```js
var data = { "20160428": { "follow": 13, "host": 6, "raid": 1, "substreak": 1, "tip": 1 }, "20160429": { "follow": 15, "host": 21, "raid": 2, "substreak": 4 }, "20160430": { "follow": 4 }, "20160501": { "follow": 11, "host": 15, "subscription": 4, "substreak": 5 }, "20160502": { "follow": 2, "host": 6, "subscription": 1, "substreak": 4 }, "20160503": { "follow": 2 } },
    grouped = {}

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (k) {
    ["follow", "host", "raid", "substreak", "tip"].forEach(function (kk) {
        grouped[kk] = grouped[kk] || [];
        grouped[kk].push(data[k][kk] || 0);
    });
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: You could replace the hard-coded properties array with `Object.keys(data[k])` in your second forEach to allow your solution to work for an arbitrary set of properties.

Comment: @MichaelL., if the array is not hard-coded, then the arrays may have not the same length.

Comment: Nothing in your code guarantees a specific array length. Dynamically creating the array only makes the code more flexible and maintainable. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7bmjdw3/).

Answer (score 1):

Don't try this at home.

```
var fields = {
  follow: 0,
  host: 0,
  raid: 0,
  substreak: 0,
  tip: 0,
  subscription: 0
};

_(data)
  .values()
  .map(x => _.assign({}, fields, x))
  .map(_.toPairs)
  .flatten()
  .groupBy(0)
  .mapValues(x => _.map(x, 1))
  .value();
```